# Unable to format setText() appropriately

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

I'm trying to set the text of a `TextView` to say "(+teamName) Score:"

What I currently have:
`textview1.setText(+teamName "Score:");` 
contains an error because the standard format is supposed to be `("" + teamName)`

**How would I make it display the `TextView` THEN quotes? Is this even possible?**

(note: `teamName` points to a string)

Comment: Any good reason my question was down voted? Its pretty simple, but perfectly viable.

Comment: I actually have no idea, the question seems fine to me. Have an upvote, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible. Use the `+` where it's needed, between the String variable (`teamName`) and `"Score: "`

```
textview1.setText(teamName + " Score:");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = String.format("%s Score", teamName);
textview1.setText(text);
```